# MongoDB the $unwind field path must be specified as a string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-compass

In mongo db compass - version 1.28.4, I am trying to use the $unwind aggregation.
A doc example is:

```
{
    "_id": "53101",
    "Version": 1,
    "Products": [{
        "_id": "ex2",
        "Type": "feature"
    }, {
        "_id": "ex1",
        "Type": "app",
        "Tags": ["app"]
    }]
}
```

When I select $unwind and insert:

```
{
  path: "$Products"
}
```

I get the error:
"MongoDB the $unwind field path must be specified as a string"

All examples I saw do exactly what I did, I can also use the same aggregation in Studio 3T, just don't know why it doesn't work in Mongodb Compass.

Comment: You syntax looks fine. Can you post how you put it into compass?

Comment: I cant post images, but the document and query are both copy/pasted

Comment: Works fine with MongoDB Compass Version 1.35.0.  As an _old-version-workaround_, you might try just `"$Products"` standing alone, i.e., no object.